# Function is performed first than reading image data

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with angular and I have a function that does the image input.

Through the inserted images, I remove them information like name, size ...
My problem is that when uploading the image (I will need to know its height and width) the upload function is executed first than the function where I get the information from that image.

As a problem I get an undifined in width and height.

The upload function is performed first than image.onload :(

Does anyone know why?

**Component.ts**

```
  detectFiles(event) {

    if (files.length < 8) {
      for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {

        this.items.push(item);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          item.url = e.target.result;
          const image = new Image();
          image.src = e.target.result;
          image.onload = function () {
            item.sizeH = image.width;
          };

        }
        formData.append('file', files[index]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[index]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is easy enough. Javascript is a sequential language but you can't be sure in your scenario which command is earlier in the stack.

The following code just says, when some event calls the onload function, execute it.

```
      image.onload = function () {
        item.sizeH = image.width;
        item.sizeV = image.height;
        self.sizeH = item.sizeH;
        self.sizeV = item.sizeV;
      };
```

Then, before anyone calls that function, you proceed and upload using the subscribe. It's common that the sequential commands will execute first.

If you did the upload inside the onload function, then you wouldn't have a problem.

```
      image.onload = function () {
        item.sizeH = image.width;
        item.sizeV = image.height;
        self.sizeH = item.sizeH;
        self.sizeV = item.sizeV;
        // upload logic here.
      };
```

Comment: I think that's right, but it didn't work correctly :(

Comment: I put the function inside reader.onload = (e: any) => {and it continues to execute first. The mistake is that the upload function is executed first than image.onload = function () {hence receiving the width and height as undefined

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with

```
 reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      item.url = e.target.result;
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = e.target.result;
      image.onload = function () {
        item.sizeH = image.width;
        item.sizeV = image.height;
        self.sizeH = item.sizeH;
        self.sizeV = item.sizeV;
      };
```

Try using like this if it helps

```
reader.onload = () => {
 // Your code to be implemented
}
```

Comment: I think that's right, but it didn't work correctly :(

Comment: That's because you need to get image data first then call the upload function.

Comment: Yes, that's it, but how can I do it correctly? From what I tried, I didn't get the results successfully :(

Comment: Once you get image data example: reader.onload = () => {
 // Your image data; then imageupload();
}